# Statistics - Probability of getting a number using combinations

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations, binomial-distribution

I have some probability questions that I'm struggling with and would appreciate some help. I included my attempt at a solution below each question.

When circuit boards used in the manufacture of compact disc players are tested, the long run percentage of defective is $5\text{%}$. Let $X=\text{#  defective boards}$ in random sample of size $n = 25$, so $X\sim\text{Bin}(25, 0.05)$.

Find the probability that the number of defective boards is:

a) At least $5$:

$$Pr(X\geq 5)=1-(\Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=1)+\Pr(X=2)+\Pr(X=3)+\Pr(X=4))$$

$= 1 - 0.9928 = 0.0072$

But the teacher's solution says the answer is $0.993$ and I'm assuming they did what I did, but didn't subtract the numbers from $1$. I don't understand why because I thought I would be counting every value when $X$ is $5$ or greater than that? For questions like $\Pr(X\leq 5)$ I would solve that by adding $\Pr(X=0)+...+\Pr(X=5)$ so I don't understand why I'm supposed to basically do the exact same thing even though the signs are flipped?

b) Between $1$ and $4$, inclusive.

For this question, I figured I would do:
$\Pr(1\leq X\leq 4) = \Pr(X=1)+...+\Pr(X=4)$

But that gives me $0.9928$ which is what I was supposed to get for part (a). The teacher's solution, however, says the answer is $0.715$ and I don't understand why.

Comment: Well, I at least recalculated the b-part and got
$$
\sum_{k=1}^4 {25 \choose{k}} 0.05^k (1-0.05)^{25-k} \approx 0.715~445
$$
On the other hand, 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^4 {25 \choose{k}} 0.05^k (1-0.05)^{25-k} \approx 0.992~835
$$

Comment: @MattiP. which makes sense since $P(X=0)\approx 0.277390$

Comment: My calculation agrees with yours for (a), but on (b) you seem to have included $P(X=0)$ in your calculation, which is a mistake, as shown by MattiP.

Comment: Sorry, so for a) would it be correct to subtract 0.992835 from 1?