# Find the probability that the number of defective boards is at least $5$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

When circuits boards used in manufacture of compact disc(CD) players are tested , the long-run percentage of defective is $5\text{%}$. Assume that there are $25$ boards in a sample. Find the probability that the number of defective boards is:

$a).$ At least 5:

I think since $20\leq n$ and $\theta \leq0.05$ it is good to use poisson approximation to binomial distribution

so $\lambda=25\times0.05=1.25  $,
$P(X=x)=\dfrac{e^{-1.25}(1.25)^x}{x!}$

we have to find

$$P(x\geq 5 )=1-P(x<5)$$

But I saw in many website as well as
[Statistics - Probability of getting a number using combinations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3281491/855456)  used only binomial distribution so I got problem why it is not used poisson distribution?

Can anyone help me is there anything wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Poisson approximation only gives an approximate answer. To get an exact answer you must use a $B(25,0.05)$ distribution. The probability can be easily found by $$1-\sum_{k=0}^4\binom{25}{k}(0.05)^k(0.95)^{25-k}$$